# Prove a language isn't regular using Myhill-Nerode thm.

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

Let $L$, a language above $\Sigma = \{x,y, (,),+,* \}$. $L$ can be defined recursively as follows:

**Basis Clause:** $x$ and $y$ are in $L$.
**Inductive Clause:** If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in $L$, then $(\alpha + \beta)$ and $(\alpha * \beta)$ are in $L$.
**Extremal Clause:** Nothing is in $L$ unless it is obtained from the above two clauses.

The guidance is to prove $L$ isn't regular using [Myhill–Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

I'm trying to think about two expressions, $\alpha \ne \beta \in L$ (and later on, a subset of $L$) such that for every $w\in \Sigma^*$: $\alpha w \in L \iff \beta w \in L$, but something isn't working.

I'd be glad for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Consider the strings $\underbrace{((\ldots((}_nx$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Oh I see. My mistake was that I assumed that $\alpha, \beta$ must be in $L$ while they can be anything in $\Sigma^*$. Thanks!

Comment: @Elimination: You’re welcome!